# Gnuplot Stacked Histogram in Black and White

Tags: png, gnuplot, monochrome

I'm trying to print stacked histogram from gnuplot into black and white png. By this I mean I would like each region in the bar to be hatched or checked alongside the legend on the side; that way when it's printed people can still identify the regions.
I've tried the following but it just leaves me with big black blobs!

```
set term pngcairo mono   size 750, 300
set output \"pies/interesting.png\"
set style data histograms
set style histogram rowstacked
set boxwidth 1 relative
set style fill solid 1 border -1
set yrange [0:100]
set ytics 10
set datafile separator \",\"
plot './functions-$MODE.csv.t' using 1 t \"\", for [i=9:13] '' using (100.*column(i)/column(15)) ti column(i)
```

How do I make my regions hatched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies for answering my own question....I've realised that a stacked histogram behaves like a normal histogram: thus if I use the styles found on this page: http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/fillstyle.html I can customise to how I would like: setting "set style fill pattern border" :

```
set term pngcairo mono size 750, 300
set output \"pies/interesting.png\"
set style data histograms
set style histogram rowstacked
set boxwidth 1 relative
set style fill pattern border
set datafile separator \",\"
plot './functions-$MODE.csv.t' using 1 t \"\", for [i=9:13] '' using (100.*column(i)/column(15)) ti column(i)
```

Results in the desired effect.